# Changing http to https and mobile links for Wikipedia

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, ssl, wikipedia

Many old posts with links to Wikipedia articles contain `http` rather than `https` links. As far as I can tell, it is better to have https link rather than http. (After all, internal links have been changed in such way: [Network-wide HTTPS: It's time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/292058).)<sup>1</sup>

And there are also many posts which contain a link to mobile Wikipedia. To my knowledge, it is better to have a link to the full site - on mobile devices the mobile version will be displayed anyway, and the users on desktops don't have to change the version.<sup>2</sup>

In both cases, there was some manual editing of such links. (I have noticed such edits on some sites that I frequent. I have included at least some stats below at least for this site.)

I was told that CMs have at their disposal some tools which can bulk replace links - and such things have been done in the past.<sup>3</sup>

**Question 1.** Would it be useful (and possible) to convert such links in bulk - at least on bigger sites? (I suppose that larger sites are likely to have more such posts than what is suitable for manual editing.)

**Question 2.** Would changing http to https be an option for some domains which are common on some site - after a list of such domains would be compiled on meta? (For example, I could imagine things like converting `http://doi.org/` to `https://doi.org/` or `http://arxiv.org` to `https://arxiv.org` on sites which often link to scientific articles.)

---

<sup>1</sup>Let us take this site as an example. I got [2433 results from search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=url%3a%22%2Ahttp://en.wikipedia.org%2A%22) and [2469 results from SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1104158/posts-containing-the-given-text-with-link-to-revisions?num=10000&text=http://en.wikipedia.org). There might be about [75 instances of edits](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1221876/posts-with-word2-in-newer-revision-but-not-in-older-revision-which-has-word1?word1=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org&word2=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org&num=1000) where http was changed to https for a Wikipedia link. On Stack Overflow I get [about 240k results from search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=active&q=url%3a%22%2Ahttp://en.wikipedia.org%2A%22). (And the queries linked above will time out for SO.)

<sup>2</sup>On Meta Stack Exchange I get [41 results from search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=url%3a%22%2Aen.m.wikipedia.org%2A%22) and [43 results from SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1104158/posts-containing-the-given-text-with-link-to-revisions?num=10000&text=en.m.wikipedia.org).
In this case I found [only 8 such edits](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1221876/posts-with-word2-in-newer-revision-but-not-in-older-revision-which-has-word1?word1=en.m.wikipedia.org&word2=en.wikipedia.org&num=1000). Searching on SO [returns about 3k results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=active&q=url%3a%22%2Aen.m.wikipedia.org%2A%22).

<sup>3</sup>One of the CMs pointed out to me some examples when such thing was done in the past: [Is it possible to mass-update broken URLs to IndianScriptures.com with HinduScriptures.in?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1969),
[Chakoteya.net links are broken](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9922), [chabadlibrary.org link structure has changed, and there are now many
broken links](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4599). There is also this example on Meta Stack Exchange: [Links to HTML versions of RFC's need to move from "tools" to "datatracker"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/367881). See also: [How to find and/or change a set of hyperlinks on a site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/313243)

Comment: I'm not personally aware of any, but are there any possible negative impacts/ side effects if the link protocol gets updated?

Comment: There may also be posts that use `secure.wikimedia.org`, which was the way to access Wikipedia via HTTPS before it was implemented on the main Wikipedia domain.

Comment: The idea is good; there might be a few cases where users deliberately use those links as examples (e.g. for navigation patterns on mobile websites). And users *keep* on posting those links (because they're not broken), so this is not a one-time effort.

Comment: That's a really good observation @Glorfindel. Somehow I did not think of the cases where  `en.m.wikipedia.org` might be necessary to help in getting across what the OP is trying to show. But I would expect this to be less likely on sites unrelated to IT (for example, MathOverflow). Re: *this is not a one-time effort.* That's certainly true for the mobile site. But I would expect that now people will include only https links to Wikipedia (since that's what they get when they visit Wikipedia). So at least the http to https conversion would be done only once.

Comment: Also related: [Can the mass-replacement tool also replace and remove?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/375121/335251)

Comment: I found this related older feature request: [Automatically convert links to popular mobile pages (such as the mobile Wikipedia) to point to the corresponding regular pages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/260843)