# Can the mass-replacement tool also replace and remove?

Tags: support, edits, hyperlinks, broken-link

Stack Exchange staff has a tool which can change a bunch of links without bumping the edited posts, see here: [How to find and/or change a set of hyperlinks on a site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/313243)

In the situation that I've seen it was simply a replacement of one string by another - for example, something like replacing all occurrences of `http://stackoverflow.com` with `https://stackoverflow.com`.

**Question.** Would the same tool be able in addition to this search/replace also remove the `.html` (or some other string) at the end of the URL?

---

I am asking in connection with this recent post: [Old Links to PlanetMath have Broken](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/34479). If you check it, it seems that replacing `http://planetmath.org/encyclopedia/` with `https://planetmath.org/` and removing `.html` at the end could fix the problem. At least, it worked in the instances which I tried - certainly, a bit more checking is necessary before something is actually done. (The linked post is on Mathematics Meta. There are such links [also on other sites](https://stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=url%3a%22%2Aplanetmath.org/encyclopedia%2A%22), but this particular site has more than 180 of them.)

But I thought that it would be better to ask about this in general - so that if similar situations occur in connection with some other domain, we'll know from the answer here, whether such links have to be edited manually or whether they can be converted en masse.

Comment: Sometimes, the substitution does not work, e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/5904/2); https://planetmath.org/Rotate is just the home page.

Comment: @Glorfindel I replaced that one with [Euclidean transformation](https://planetmath.org/euclideantransformation) - content seems to be the same as in the [Wayback Machine snapshot](https://web.archive.org/web/20071003125405///planetmath.org/encyclopedia/Rotate.html) that you provided. In any case, it is good to know that there are some problematic cases - and it is also a reason to be cautious.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's just a simple Find & Replace tool which doesn't support wildcards. In that case, that means the operation needs to be performed once for every individual PlanetMath page that is being linked to (because the `.html` needs to be removed).

It's a trivial change for my Broken Link Repairer script, which does have the disadvantages that 1) it bumps the post and 2) on some sites (I saw a couple of Physics hits), it can only suggest edits. It has the advantages of checking whether the new link actually works and repairing other broken links (if any).

Comment: Confirmed - the url replace tool that we use is a strict (case-sensitive) find-replace. No wildcards, no regex (by design).

Comment: Does the script have a rate-limiting feature?

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum yes, configurable. See [here](https://gist.github.com/Glorfindel83/9d954d34385d2ac2597bbe864466259f#how-much-does-it-do), except that these broken link scripts (I have a couple of them running) run once every three days.