# Can the link replacement tool be used on typos in regular text?

Tags: support, edits, spelling

I discovered a simple typo that is pretty prevalent. Can this be fixed with the "link" replacement tool, given that it's actually "[a simple Find and Replace tool](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375122/323179)"? (That linked Q&A is very related, but didn't make it clear if non-links specifically can be replaced.)

And if so, is there a lower limit to how many instances there would need to be in order to get something like this approved? In this specific case, there are 100+ posts with misspellings (and 500+ posts with proper spellings, possibly with overlap) on a single site. The site is also not Stack Overflow, so I would have to edit a few posts every day for the next month plus in order to fix it without causing any problems. That's really hard to commit to, even for me. (In fact, I think I've been aware of this specific problem for over a year, maybe multiple years.)

The following patterns should match almost all the typos, except for a few that have unusual punctuation bordering it (underscore represents space, and "word" is a placeholder):

- `_Word_`
- `_Word,`
- `_Word.`
- `_word_`
- `_word,`
- `_word.`

This probably wouldn't break anything, which I could verify more rigorously with SEDE beforehand. (And if it was going to break a few posts, it would be easier to revert those changes than to do everything manually.)

---

I know that there are community-run projects out there that automate edits. However, these still bump the post and therefore need to rate limit themselves. If you were to spend some time looking for suitable typos to automate away, I'm certain you'd find enough to keep such a bot busy for years. Hence this question.

Comment: Glorfindel is perfectly happy with running editing scripts on sites for long periods of time. He once ran a script that edited one post per three days for a year to update a user's ID in shared links when the user's ID changed due to an account merge. I'm sure you could ask him to do it.

Comment: I'm curious, what are the typos?

Comment: Posts related to misspellings of [Cauchy–Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality) on MathOverflow Meta: [Best way to correct "Cauchy-Schwarz" misspellings](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/5262) and [Misspelling of Cauchy-Schwarz](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3952).
The same inequality was mentioned in this post, too: [Edit session for wrong spelling of mathematicians and mathematical concepts](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13730) (on [math.meta.se]).

Comment: On [math.meta.se], we started a list like this: [List of commonly misspelled words](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/30918). It was long time ago - my guess its that it has been forgotten - and nobody actually uses it
I would not be surprised if there were various similar discussions on per-site-metas where automated edits were suggested as an option.

Comment: @Martin: Most words in that list look like one-off typos (never to appear again with any reasonable probability), very far from a count of 100 or more. [Such lists](https://pmortensen.eu/EditOverflow/_Wordlist/EditOverflowList_latest.html#definitely) very quickly becomes unwieldy...

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum That is certainly true - and when that post was made, I guess we were overly enthusiastic about editing various minor things, including typos. My intention was mainly to give some examples when something similar was discussed on per-site metas. (Although if we look at [Cauchy-Schwartz on Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Cauchy+Schwartz%22), the search returns over 800 posts - so this seems like a rather common misspelling.

Comment: Without specifics, the answer is always it depends. Even the highly specific *case-sensitive* "[StackOverflow](https://pmortensen.eu/EditOverflow/_Wordlist/EditOverflowList_latest.html#Stack_Overflow)" could result in false positives (e.g., part of a misplaced space in a ([Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_%28programming_language%29)/[.NET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework)) exception name or part of a URL). And with pattern matching, the false positive rate is much higher.

Comment: (Notes: 1) Wikipedia uses an [en dash](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/en_dash#Noun), [em dash](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/em_dash#Noun), or similar (I am not sure which one) in [Cauchy–Schwarz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality). 2) [Schwartzian transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) does include the "t" whereas [Schwarzschild radius  / metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_radius) doesn't...)